# Need xpath expression to loop through xmldocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, xpath

trying to parse this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<directoryresponse xmlns="https://www.sisow.nl/Sisow/REST" version="1.0.0">
    <directory>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>01</issuerid>
            <issuername>ABN Amro Bank</issuername>
        </issuer>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>02</issuerid>
            <issuername>ASN Bank</issuername>
        </issuer>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>04</issuerid>
            <issuername>Friesland Bank</issuername>
        </issuer>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>05</issuerid>
            <issuername>ING</issuername>
        </issuer>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>06</issuerid>
            <issuername>Rabobank</issuername>
        </issuer>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>07</issuerid>
            <issuername>SNS Bank</issuername>
        </issuer>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>08</issuerid>
            <issuername>RegioBank</issuername>
        </issuer>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>09</issuerid>
            <issuername>Triodos Bank</issuername>
        </issuer>
        <issuer>
            <issuerid>10</issuerid>
            <issuername>Van Lanschot Bankiers</issuername>
        </issuer>
    </directory>
</directoryresponse>
```

Here's my code:

```
XPath = "//directoryresponse/directory/issuer/issuerid"
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = XML.SelectNodes(XPath)
```

but nodelist.count=0...why?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to format the XML so we can read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace, so you code should be:
C#:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("a.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "https://www.sisow.nl/Sisow/REST");

var result = doc.SelectNodes("//ns:issuer/ns:issuerid", mgr);

foreach (XmlElement item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load("a.xml")

Dim mgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "https://www.sisow.nl/Sisow/REST")

Dim result As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//ns:issuer/ns:issuerid", mgr)

Dim item As XmlElement
For Each item In result
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText)
Next
```

Comment: Ok, thanks!
And how would I then select all issuers and then for all issuers get the underlying node values?
I tried various things:
        Dim result As XmlNodeList = XML.SelectNodes("//ns:issuer", mgr)
        Dim item As XmlElement
        For Each item In result
            Console.WriteLine(item.SelectSingleNode("/ns:issuerid", mgr).InnerText)
            Console.WriteLine(item.SelectSingleNode("/issuerid").InnerText)
            Console.WriteLine(item.SelectSingleNode("issuerid").InnerText)
        Next

Comment: @Floran, Use: `item.SelectSingleNode("ns:issuerid", mgr).InnerText`, i.e. XPath should be `ns:issuerid` instead of `/ns:issuerid` or `/issuerid`. Consider upvoting or accepting helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, I always do that after the problem was fixed, which it is now!

Answer (score 1):

Your XML contains a namespace. You will have to alias the namespace with the NamespaceManager and include the alias in your XPath. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx for details.